# Rails views with subclassed controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm relatively new to rails development. I have a `UserBaseController` and then I have a `MaleUserController` which is a subclass from the `UserBaseController` and a `FemaleUserController` which is also a subclass from the `UserBaseClass`.

In `app/views/user_base` I have an `index.html.erb` file but I want a separate view for only the `MaleUserController`, so I have `app/views/user_base/male_user/index.html.erb` but for some reason the index file from `app/views/user_base` is being loaded.

Am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put your male_user folder on the same level as user_base:

```
app/views/male_user/index.html.erb
```

If that doesn't work then tell the controller where to look:

```
class MaleUsersController < UserBaseController
  prepend_view_path 'app/views/male_users'
```

P.S Where is your `gender_not_specified_user.rb`? ;)